# Overloading of << operator using iterator as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, operator-overloading

I`d like to print enum values as text and use for it overloading. Suppose I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

enum enm{
    One,
    Two
};

class Complex{
public:
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::unordered_multiset<int>::const_iterator i){
    switch (*i){
        case One:{
            return out<<"One";
        }
        case Two:{
            return out << "Two";
        }
    }
}
void func(std::unordered_multiset<int> _v);
};

void Complex:: func(std::unordered_multiset<int> _v){
    _v.insert(One);
    _v.insert(Two);
    for (std::unordered_multiset<int>::const_iterator i(_v.begin()), end(_v.end()); i != end; ++i){
        std::cout <<"Num: " << *i <<std::endl; //need to get here "One", "Two" instead of 0, 1
    }
}

int main(){
    Complex c;
    std::unordered_multiset<int> ms;
    c.func(ms);
    return 0;   
}
```

The problem is this variant doesn`t work. So, I get 0, 1 instead of One, Two. Have no ideas how to do it properly.
Thank you for help!

Comment: As a side note: Don't use `_` as variable prefix, that's reserved for c++ implementation internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you changed `i` to `*i` in order for your program to compile.  In order to print the iterator you must do `i`, but this fails with a compiler error.

The problem is that the insertion operator is defined as a friend within the class on its first declaration, so the lookup to find this operator can only depend on namespaces and classes associated with the argument types, a lookup referred to as [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) or Koenig lookup.

Since `std::ostream` and `unordered_multiset::const_iterator` are not asscoiated with `Complex` (see [`ADL#Details`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl#Details)), lookup fails to find the insertion operator.

The solution is to declare the function outside of the class so that normal [unqualified lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) for the operator takes place:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, std::unordered_multiset<int>::const_iterator);
class Complex { .. };
```

I would recommend however that you *define* the operator outside of the class, as it doesn't seem to need to access private/protected members of `Complex` (part of the purpose of befriending entities).

Comment: Declare the function outside of the class is a decision for one part of the problem. 
Another is -- iterator as a parameter, which is not a part of class Complex. As I understand, overloading function must take at least one argument that is of Complex class type. That`s why I`m wrong passing iterator as a parameter. So, are there any variants to print enum values as text from multiset using overloading or not?:)

Comment: @user3856196 [Here's an example that creates a new formatting facet for custom output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cada1d56a6898890) . Turn it on using `os << print_alpha_num` and off with `os << no_print_alpha_num`.