# Switching on iterator

Tags: c++, enums, stl, iterator, switch-statement

I try to print enum elements as text instead of numbers. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

enum enm{
    One,
    Two
};

class Complex{
public:
    void func(std::unordered_multiset<int> _v);
    void name(std::unordered_multiset<int>::const_iterator i);
};

void Complex:: name(std::unordered_multiset<int>::const_iterator i){
    switch(*i) {
            case One:
                std::cout<<"One"<<std::endl;
                break;
            case Two:
                std::cout<<"Two"<<std::endl;
                break;
    }
}

void Complex:: func(std::unordered_multiset<int> _v){
    _v.insert(One);
    _v.insert(Two);
    for (std::unordered_multiset<int>::const_iterator i(_v.begin()), end(_v.end()); i != end; ++i){
        std::cout<<"Res: "<<name(i)<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    Complex c;
    std::unordered_multiset<int> ms;
    c.func(ms);
    return 0;   
}
```

I have a function `name(std::unordered_multiset<int>::const_iterator i)`, where use switch on iterator. The problem is - it fails. But I have no ideas how to fix this and why it happens.

**Edit:**
I have:
std::`std::cout<<"Res: "<<name(i)<<std::endl;`
not only: `name(i);`

**Solution**
Hence, it works if:
`std::cout<<"Res: "<<std::endl;
name(i);`

Comment: *"it fails"* How? [Runs fine for me](http://cpp.sh/2a2t)

Comment: I get this -- error: forming reference to void

Comment: Is this not the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119555/overloading-of-operator-using-iterator-as-a-parameter) you asked yesterday?

Comment: What compiler? Can you edit your post to include the *full* error message

Comment: Barry, it`s another version, without oveloading

Comment: @user3856196, you should provide your compiler name & version & args, because your code compiles fine on latest [gcc](http://rextester.com/WYBS47197), [clang](http://rextester.com/FMY29732) and [vc++](http://rextester.com/TUHA56781)

Comment: Which compiler are you using , it giving proper out on gcc 4.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Order of print statements will be lexicographically sored , as urordered map ,prints sorted output.

Comment: Is there any possible way out?

Comment: the answer is not relative to question and no, it will not `lexicographically sored , as urordered map`